# What is the correct date syntax to always have updated data in sql?

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift, refresh

I'm writing a query where every week I need to have updated data starting from the last 60 days to the latest available update.

Can anyone tell me which is the correct syntax or wildcard?
Thanks

The following syntax is not correct because now it will give me the last 60 days updated to date but in a week I will have the same data which will not be updated:

WHERE date_dd BETWEEN to_date('2022-12-26','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2023-01-20','YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score 0):

To determine the last n-days please use a system functions like datadd in t-sql on Microsoft SQL Server.
You can test the following in SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio):

```
declare @dtFrom datetime = dateadd( day, -60, getdate() );
declare @dtTo   datetime = getdate();
select @dtFrom, @dtTo; -- only to show the interval
select * from <your table name here> where date_dd between @dtFrom and @dtTo;
```

On other dbms the dateadd function is also present, for oracle the name is the same but syntax is slightly different. Please refer to the appropriate online manuals.